# Namespaces in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, namespaces, delphi-xe2

I've got two bpl packages: Core and Business, used by one application.
Core.bpl contains unit User.pas with TUser class in it. TUser in Core.bpl has only two base fields: Login and Password.
I want to expand TUser class in Business package with new field: UserName. And I want to name business unit as the base unit: User.pas.

So, I create a new unit User.pas in Business.bpl and place there TUser class that extends TUser from Core.bpl.
Now I need to divide TUser from Core.bpl and TUser from Business.bpl. And I need to use "power of namespaces" here :)

I've read [Embarcadero doc page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi). They say that one can set the default namespace for package with naming it, e.g. Base.Core.
I named my packages as Base.Core.bpl and Extra.Business.bpl. And compiled files are named so.
But all units in them are still named as they were before: User.pas -> User.dcu.

Now I've got two classes TUser in modules User.pas: one in package Base.Core.bpl, other in package Extra.Business.bpl.
User.pas in Extra looks like

```
unit User;
interface
uses
  Base.User;
type
  TUser = class(Base.User.TUser)
  end;
```

But when I want to compile it, I've got a window: "Remove User. Unit(s) User were found in required package Base."

What have I do to inherit new TUser from Base.User.TUser like it can be in Java, for example?

P.S. Just in case, I use Delphi XE2 IDE.

Comment: Shouldn't you name them as 'Unit Base.User' and 'Unit Business.User', if you want to use such notation?

Comment: There are many units in Core and in Business... And all of them are in SVN :( Renaming all of them is the last way... May be, one can do it easier?

Comment: I'm with you. The documentation says one thing. But the program behaves completely differently.

Comment: If it's feasable set the "default namespace". It was in "directories/conditionals" in project options in earlier versions. Somehow I can't find it now, but it's possible to add it as an additional option in "other options" in "compiling".

Comment: What should I pass to option "other options" in "compiling"?

Comment: @omickron - F.i.: `--default-namespace="Base.Core"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default namespace appears to be Portal cake–it's a lie. The documentation you link to does not match the program.

I made this program:

**MyCompany.Programs.MyProgram.dpr**

```
program MyCompany.Programs.MyProgram;

uses
  MyUnit in 'MyUnit.pas';

begin
end.
```

**MyUnit.pas**

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

implementation

end.
```

And the resulting .dcu file is named `MyUnit.dcu`. According to the documentation that you linked to it should be named `MyCompany.Programs.MyUnit.dcu`.

I believe that you will have to specify the namespace explicitly in the unit name.

Comment: "you will have to specify the namespace explicitly in the unit name" That's a pity...

Comment: For the life of my I can't understand why the program doesn't match the documentation. The documentation is very clear. It's hard to see how we could be misunderstanding it.

Comment: Does this happen in XE3 too, don't you know?

Comment: Looks like a bug. May be in Delphi, may be in docs... However thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, in Delphi 2009-XE setting the default namespace in the project options resulted in it being prepended to any generated dcus. If the default namespace was `MyCompany.Programs.MyProgram` and the unit file was named `MyUnit.pas` the resulting dcu was `MyCompany.Programs.MyProgram.MyUnit.dcu`. Also if the unit was explicitly named `MyCompany.Programs.MyProgram.MyUnit.pas` setting the default namespace allowed other units to refer to it simply as `MyUnit`. This setting was removed in XE2 but as Sertac pointed out in the question comments the command-line setting still exists.